# Delete an object automatically after 5 minutes

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-2.2

I'm trying to create a function that automatically delete an object after 5 minutes from publication.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

import datetime

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        )
    publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(
    default=timezone.now,
    blank=True,
    )

    @property
    def delete_after_five_minutes(self):
        time = self.publishing_date + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
        if time > datetime.datetime.now():
            e = Event.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            e.delete()
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The problem is that all objects are deleted and not only the objects that I wish.

Comment: You should swap to comparison, so `time < datetime.datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should swap the comparison, so:

```
if time < datetime.datetime.now():
    # ...
```

or perhaps more readable:

```
if self.publishing_date < datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(minutes=5):
    # ...
```

since this thus means that five minutes *before now* is still after the time when the `Event` was published.

That being said, it might be better *not* to delete the values, or at least not immediately, but make a manager, that simply "hides" these objects. You can then later, periodically, remove the elements.

We can make such manager with:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class EventManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            publishing_date__gte=timezone.now()-timezone.timedelta(minutes=5)
        )
```

and then use this manager like:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = EventManager()
```

Then `Event.objects` will only retrieve `Event`s that have been published less than five minutes ago.

You can periodically remove such events with:

```
Event._base_manager.filter(
    publishing_date__lt=timezone.now()-timezone.timedelta(minutes=5)
).delete()
```

This will then remove these `Event`s in "bulk".

Comment: Oh great, it's run! I had no idea that is possible "to put in standby" an object using something like `EventManager`. I must improve my skills with Python and Django. Thank you :)

Comment: @MassimilianoMoraca: there is also a `django-softdelete` package that might/might not help: https://github.com/scoursen/django-softdelete

Comment: Note that filtering the base queryset in the default manager is to be done with caution, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#default-managers.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: I agree. Probably it is better to use a package like `softdelete` since then one can use names like `.active_objects` and `.all_objects` for the managers.