# How do you delete a Django Object after a given amount of time?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm a new Django developer, and working on a website where users can store csv files outputted by the website to a field of a model along with a randomly generated key. I referred to this link:

[Delete an object automatically after 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267862/delete-an-object-automatically-after-5-minutes)

for more information, but when I implemented it onto my own project, it did not work.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
import datetime
import os
# Create your models here.

class TemporaryFile(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
    data = models.FileField()
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    @property
    def delete_after_time(self):
        if self.time_created < datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(minutes=1):
            self_file = TemporaryFile.objects.get(pk = self.pk)
            data = self.data
            os.remove(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, data))
            os.remove(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, data))
            self_file.delete()
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Because it is difficult to store a csv file to a model field, I instead saved it to the default storage that Django has, which for some reason made two copies of the csv file and stored one in the media root and another one in the base directory. That is why I have the os.remove functions. Can somebody please tell me why the object and files are not being deleted?

Comment: This is best be done by a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) that checks for expired files and deletes them. It should be run on a schedule by a cron job or similar.

Comment: You may have misinterpreted the OP's wording of his question, as his implementation does not automatically delete an object after 5 minutes. His implementation only deletes the objects after calling the `delete_after_five_minutes` property. Therefore, you still have to fetch the object in question and calling `my_object.delete_after_five_minutes`. That said, you can use cron to automate the deletion process. Django has a [package](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jobs_scheduling.html) similar to cron for doing that.

Comment: @KlausD. Can you please provide an example of your implementation? Especially the cron job part, I just spent 4 hours searching the web for an answer but none of the solutions worked... If you want to look at my other question and answer it I'll greatly appreciate it!